# How to refer a class field by metainfo (just like a .class)

Tags: java, reflection

I dont know many things about java reflection but is there a way (or if not why not) to refer a class field in java by other than a simple String like

```
myClass.class.getField ("myField")
```

and instead do something like this, **that could be checked by a compiler:**

```
myClass.class.getField (myField.field)
```

or i dont know maybe

```
myClass.class.getField (myClass.myField.field)
```

So my goal is to refer a field (private or whatever), that a compiler could check it exists, like u can refer a class and the compiler can check it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's nothing within Java which allows this. Yes, it would be nice - but it's not present at the moment.

The closest we have is the promise of method literals in Java 8, in the general lambda expression feature, but as far as I'm aware this won't apply to fields.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the point of reflection.

From the [Oracle Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

> Reflection is commonly used by programs which require the ability to examine or modify the runtime behavior of applications running in the Java virtual machine. ...

Reflection allows the application to examine itself during **runtime**. So a compile time check is not what you get when using reflection.

Though, you can check a fields existence in your code at runtime, before accessing it.

Comment: yes reflection is for dynamic access, but some information is known at compile time, like this piece of what fields are part of some class; so i want the compiler to be able to check this information at compile time (only if i pass 'statically' the name of the field  of course, not if i pass it like an unknown string it cant do anything about it, its full dynamic, thats ok); this way the compiler could later avert me that some fields reffered in my dynamic code dissapeared and i should remove them

Answer (score 1):

You can almost do it:

```
Field field = myClass.class.getField (someField.getName());
```

Comment: what is this someField? what type is it?

Comment: It's meant to be any field you have a reference to - one that has the name of the target you're after. The type wouldn't have an effect on the success of calling `getField()`, but you could assert it has the same type by comparing `field.getType()`

Comment: yes...but i dont have the reference as yet, i only have the name and i dont want to use a string to get it but a more static approach that can be checked by a compiler! (like when u say MyClass.class compiler says its ok because MyClass exists)

Answer (score 0):

`getField` method of `Class` 
expects a String , so you have to provide String name of the field.

What you can do is first call `getFields()` method a class and make of call out of those fields. Following are the Steps to achieve it:

1. Make call to `Class.getFields()` which will return `Field` array.
2. Now you have a list of Fields which exists for sure in your class, so you can make a call `getField(field.getName())`